# how to set parameter for different condition in data frame of Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, analytics

I am filtering Data of two columns in a data frame. What should be the correct code for it. "Over" Column in want set more than 20 and for "Batting_team" Column it should be set as "Sun Riser" what is the syntax of code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("deliveries.csv")
a=df[df['over' and  'batting_team']>=20 & ="Sunrisers Hyderabad"]
```

Error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-95-39da624fe094>", line 5
    a=df[df['over' and  'batting_team']>=20 & ="Sunrisers Hyderabad"]                                           
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: df[df['over']>=20 &  df['batting_team'] == "Sunrisers Hyderabad"]

Comment: The code is not running